# List instance in not created after deploying a feature which has this list definition and instance

Tags: list-definition, site-definition

I have a site definition: 
inside that I am creating a list definition & instance,
one visual web part.
I am creating a feature and putting all these list definition, instance and visual web part into the feature (it is site scoped feature).
and deployed the site definition

Issue:
when I am creating a new sub site, VWP is there and list definition is there (our custom list is available in add an app list) but the list is not already created in sub site.

Comment: I would change the scope of the list instance from Site to Web

Comment: Hi MdMazzotti, If i changed the scoped to Web, i am unable to deploy the feature; "The Project Item "siteDef" cannot be deployed through a Feature with Web scope" error is displayed.

Comment: I meant, create a new feature with your site instance, and scope it to web